# How to take information from a database and use it in a select

Tags: java, jsp

I am trying to take author information from my database and use it to populate a drop down list in a form for creating books. I have tried:

```
<select name="authorId">
     <c:forEach items="${dropDownAuthors}" var="items">                                       
          <option value="${items.authorId}">${items.authorName}</option>
     </c:forEach>
</select>
```

But my drop-down is empty, I did an alert of the drop-down authors and that works fine, I am really confused as what the problem is.
edit: ok guys I feel really stupid now, because of your comments I double checked and i forgot the tag libraries which was my only problem and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your are using JSF (and you will when you have setup an actual JEE App Webprofile like Version 6 or 7) then you can use the selectOneMenu tag to create a form select field.

Example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{user.favCoffee2}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{user.favCoffee2Value}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Copied from: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-dropdown-box-example/

And make sure that you have registered the namespaces

> xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
>
> xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"

Comment: I tried but it didnt work but then i realized i didnt have taglib so now the way i had it works

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you really want forTokens here rather than forEach....

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title><c:forTokens> Tag Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forTokens items="Zara,nuha,roshy" delims="," var="name">
   <c:out value="${name}"/><p>
</c:forTokens>
</body>
</html>
```

From http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm.

Comment: I tried but it didnt work but then i realized i didnt have taglib so now the way i had it works

Comment: Awesome. Glad my answer helped you :)